# Run a function at the first keypress event on an input

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, onkeypress

I have an `input` element with an `onkeypress` event that runs a function, `change()`. The problem is that the function doesn't run for the very first keypress. For example, I have to type **55** instead of **5** to get the function to update, and the value it takes is **5**. Somehow, it doesn't recognize the most recent keypress. I tried adding other events, such as `onfocus` and `onselect`, to no avail. Here is the code for the `input`:

```
<input id="x" type="text" size="1" maxlength="2" onkeypress="change()" onfocus="change()" onselect="change()" onblur="change()" onchange="change()"></input>
```

[image: JSFiddle]

Comment: Would using `onkeyup` instead work? Also, what does the `change()` function do and how do you know it is not running it the first time?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I had no idea that existed. Please post it as an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that the `onkeypress` event triggers before the value is inserted.

If you want to capture the value after the key has been pressed you could use the `onkeyup` event instead and see if that works better.

Answer (score 2):

you might to try this event

```
onKeyUp="change()"
```

link no longer valid

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because the value is just set after you release the key. When I try it with `onkeyup` its working

http://jsfiddle.net/j8B8b/2/